# Google Photos Library API IDs are invalid

Tags: google-photos, google-photos-api

Cached IDs of media items, albums and enrichment items stopped working.

For example, calling `mediaItems.get` with a media item ID that was stored returns the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid media item ID.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The format of all IDs returned by the Google Photos Library API changed on September 5.

If you have stored IDs such as albums ids, media item ids, or enrichment item ids before 5th September 2018, these will no longer work as the format of the IDs has changed recently. Obtain new IDs for use in your application.

You can make a request again to retrieve the new IDs, for example by listing the library contents, albums or submitting another search request.

See the [API release notes](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/support/release-notes#2018-09-05) for more information

Comment: Google just broke the API... that's really annoying. The IDs were not "cached", they were "saved" and I was using them. Thank you for the information.