# Id of photos in Google photos API

Tags: google-photos

I am using the Google photos API
We use this to add and reference photos to google photos.
Save the ID that is issued when adding a photo, link it with other information by using it, and reference the photo again.
After photos were added, it was possible in the above method during August, but in September the ID was changed, and I could not refer to it properly.
It means that the ID when added and the ID when referring have been changed.
Does this mean that the ID is automatically updated every certain period?
By the way, the photos in google photos have not been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

The IDs changed as part of the 5 September 2018 release of the Google Photos Library API. 
This was a once-off change during the developer preview. Now that the API has entered [general availability](https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/09/build-new-experiences-with-google.html), you should not expect breaking changes like this.

There's some more background in this question: [Google Photos Library API IDs are invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52175632/google-photos-library-api-ids-are-invalid)